# ABAP: Search in MS Word document for a word to check if exists

Tags: ms-word, abap

This is a very specific question and I do not know if there is a solution. I am trying to find a way to search in a word document and check if there is a specific word in it. All this will happen from an abap program.
Thanks in advance.
Elias

Comment: Is the document available in .doc or .docx format?

Comment: In .doc format.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using OLE automation. These sources might be a good starting point:

- https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/ABAP+-+OLE+Automation+using+MS-Word
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Post a snippet, please